# What would be the isolated and limit points of B={1/n + 1/m}?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a set

B={1/n + 1/m for n,m natural numbers}

1. Limit points of B?

I think only limit points of B are 0 and 1, and every point in B can not be an limit point.

2. Does it contain isolated points?

Yes, by part 1) every point in B is not a limit point, so every point in B is isolated point.

For part 1)

I chose epsilon to be 1/(mn)

then every neighborhood of B would be (m+n-1)/(mn) < x < (m+n+1)/(mn), which implies that intersection of this neighborhood with B is (m+n)/(mn).

Is it right proof?

Comment: You are correct in thinking that every point of $B$ is isolated, but you missed a bunch of limit points of $B$. Consider the subset $$\left\{\frac13+\frac1m:m\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\subseteq B\;;$$ can you find a limit point of it (and hence of $B$)?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: is every point of $B$ isolated? Isn't $1/3 = 1/6 + 1/6 \in B$ and a limit point of $B$? (Sorry if I'm being stupid.)

Comment: isn't 1/3 limit point?

Comment: @Rob: No, you’re right; I was thinking of a slightly different version that removes that possibility.

Comment: then all limit points of B would be 1, 1/2, 1/3 ,1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9 and 0?

Comment: @Garsa: Yes, it is. And ignore what I said about all of the points of $B$ being isolated: as Rob points out, the ones that are of the form $\frac1n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ are limit points.

Comment: @Garsa: Why stop with $\frac19$? **Every** $\frac1n$ with $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ is a limit point of $B$, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: Oh I see and 0 is also limit point?

Comment: @Garsa: Yes, it is.

Comment: @Garsa: My pleasure!